# Flutter Snackbar update state

Tags: flutter

It seems `setState` does not update content inside the current `snackBar`. Is there a way to achive this or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

use StatefulBuilder as a parent widget in snackbar , wrap the content of snackbar with StatefulBuilder widget and check out how to use StatefulBuilder